# how to stub this class

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class called Board. Within it I init a grid.

I want to create a mock or stub (not sure which) for the board for an rspec spec.

I can't figure out how the stub or mock should look...

```
stub_board = stub('board') 
stub_board.stub(:[]).with(:b2).and_return("O")
```

I do not know...for the sake of the test I want to write I'd like to have a number of O's on the board.

Can anyone assist?

Just for fyi here is the actual class Board....thanks for any help, I've been staring at this for 3 days.

```
class Board
attr_reader :grid

def initialize(cell_value = " ")
  @grid = {
    a1: cell_value, a2: cell_value, a3: cell_value,
    b1: cell_value, b2: cell_value, b3: cell_value,
    c1: cell_value, c2: cell_value, c3: cell_value
  }
end

def drawgrid
  board = "\n"
  board << "a #{@grid[:a1]}|#{@grid[:a2]}|#{@grid[:a3]} \n"
  board << "----------\n"
  board << "b #{@grid[:b1]}|#{@grid[:b2]}|#{@grid[:b3]} \n"
  board << "----------\n"
  board << "c #{@grid[:c1]}|#{@grid[:c2]}|#{@grid[:c3]} \n"
  board << "----------\n"
  board << "  1 2 3\n"
end

def space_taken?(cell_location)
  @grid[cell_location] != " "
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my thoughts. This does not have to be stubing or mocking. Just start with simple testing and than you can give more power by stubing, mocking or whatever.

You have an object of Board class. This object has input things like attribute `grid` and `initialize` method and it has output things like `drawgrid` and `space_taken?`. So the idea of testing to set input things and expact specific output things. It might be:

```
describe Board do

  describe "drawgrid" do

    it "shuold generate default string" do
      board = Board.new
      board.drawgrid.should == "here's your string"
    end

    it "should generate string with cell_value '*'" do
      board = Board.new('*')
      board.drawgrid.should == "string with '*' cell value"
    end

    # and so on
  end

  describe "space_taken?" do

    it "should set cell value" do
      board = Board.new
      board.space_taken?(:a1).should be_false
      board.grid[:a1] = '!'
      board.space_taken?(:a1).should be_true
    end

    # and so on
  end
end
```

You can use the code coverage analysis tool which will help you to find the uncovered lines, for example [SimpleCov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov)